# Will Terrafrom allow new EC2(s) to be deployed into established cloud infrastructure

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

Is it possible to deploy additional resources like EC2(s) into the same VPC once deployed using terraform? Concerned that the established resources in the VPC: EC2(s), NIC configurations, and VPC subnets will be overwritten?

I am wanting to deploy additional EC2(s) without overwriting the VPC, subnets, and established EC2?   I am wondering if the subnets will be recreated hence impacting working EC2(s). (Looking for way to deploy additional EC2(s) once the infrastructure is established with Transit Gateways or peering, Internet Gateway (IGW) which are in production.)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend importing your existing resources into Terraform so it's all managed by TF. To do this, you would create `Resource` objects for all the existing resources then run `terraform import ...` on each, you can start with a basic `Resource` object, then after importing, run `terraform plan` and make any changes that it detects as drift (or the changes it wants to make to the resource). Keep going until `terraform plan` reports it's not going to change anything, now they are completely managed by TF.

If you don't want to do that you can describe existing AWS resources using the TF `Data` object, that's what they are meant for. Then just reference those `Data` objects in your new EC2 `Resource` objects.